# Querying edge ID between two vertex IDs

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientjs

I have this `User` vertex and `friends` edge. I know two of the users who are friends and one of them wants to unfriend the other. How am I supposed to delete that edge between given vertexes?

So far running **both** `DELETE EDGE FROM :player1 TO :player2 WHERE @class = "friends"` **and** `DELETE EDGE FROM :player2 TO :player1 WHERE @class = "friends"` (with proper params ofc.) to make sure it's deleted works fine for me but that doesn't feel *elegant* enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it in a single query:

```
 DELETE EDGE friends FROM [:player1, :player2] TO [:player1, :player2]
```

In case you also have edges from a vertex to itself (eg. from player1 to player1) and you don't want to delete them, you can add a condition:

```
 DELETE EDGE friends FROM [:player1, :player2] TO [:player1, :player2]
 WHERE out <> in
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response Luigi. Looks like this works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks!